# navbar at bottom hides the table - how to fix in bootstrap 3/ custom css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, datatables

as my screenshot below shows, my table pagination is hidden by navbar at bottom. 
[image]

I tried

```
{
float:left;
clear:both;
}
```

on enclosing div of table. but that did not help.
I also pasting the screenshot of the HTML taken from chrome developer tools. I am using datatable jquery plugin that autogenerates the pagination and hence it not available in raw html. I want dont want the pagination to be hidden behind the bottom-navbar. how to fix this?

[image]

EDIT:

In the firefox, the pagination looks fine. but each row of the table extends outside as shown below

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing CSS. Did you try to set `overflow: auto / visible;` on .container class?

Comment: @Doodlebunch  overflow did not help. I just tried it.

Comment: Do you have a demo link or something? Not easy to guess.

Comment: @Doodlebunch I use datatable-jquery plug-in. so the row data is loaded dynamically. only the developer tools or firebug shows the actual data. I am wondering how can I share the link of the html/css/js

Comment: We can do nothing without seeing some code

Comment: @KarimAG: css code is basically bootstrap 3.0. you can find that online. as I mentioned, the table data are dynamically created. for all the class/div, I have pasted the image of developer tools

Answer (score 1):

have you tried putting the table within a div then setting the overflow:visible property on the div, and a clear:both property on the bottom navbar?

also it looks like the table is being pushed over to the right in the bottom image. If that's only happening in Firefox, you might have to adjust the margin if Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  table#search_table{
     margin:[difference];
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference here mean? I have divs around table.

Comment: what properties do you have on the navbar? can you paste the entire HTML and CSS code?

Comment: if you want to share the code with the dynamically generated table data, just copy the HTML from "view source" after it's generated in your browser

Comment: the view source does not show the row data that is created dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution what works for me.

First I wrapped the table in a div. Then I added an additional div as "Spacer". Look following code snippet, use size you need:

```
           <div>            
              <table id="vertragsTabelle" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Zuständige Stelle</th>
                    <th>Auszubildender</th>
                    <th>Beruf</th>
                    <th>Fachrichtung</th>
                    <th>Schwerpunkt</th>
                    <th>Betrieb</th>
                    <th>Beginn</th>
                    <th>Ende</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Zuständige Stelle</th>
                    <th>Auszubildender</th>
                    <th>Beruf</th>
                    <th>Fachrichtung</th>
                    <th>Schwerpunkt</th>
                    <th>Betrieb</th>
                    <th>Beginn</th>
                    <th>Ende</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
          </div>

          <!-- SPACER -->
          <div class="spacer" style="height:50px"></div>
```